# Is there an Octave function to remove outlier percentiles of data from a distribution?

Tags: sorting, octave, distribution, normal-distribution, outliers

I am trying to sort a large dataset to contain only the top 99% of the data (within a normal distribution) . Is there a function that already exists in Octave to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the following example code:

```
n = 1000;
a = randn(1,n);
q1 = sort(a)(n*0.01:n);
```